# Set up domain on Apache server

Tags: 16.04, apache2, dns, vps

Hey I have got a VPS which I have installed Apache on so I can do some web development. Say I have a domain name. How would I link that to the Apache server.

I am running Ubuntu 16.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your DNS you make an A record that points to your VPS ip
that's it.

your website will be in */var/www/html*
add your website stuff

open up VIM (or the editor of your choice)

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

change your ServerAdmin to your email

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

to restart apache and you are good to go

Comment: Is it just the ServerAdmin I need to change? Also is it the email I used for the domain registration?

Comment: ServerAdmin, not necessarily the one you used for the domain registration,
anything better than having it as webmaster@localhost

You may also want to add/change the 
ServerName www.yoursite.com